# Cannot delete EntityFramework.dll from asp.net core application

Tags: iis, .net-core

We have two servers with IIS. When we copy files to the first server, and the asp.net core application is currently running there then even thought we:

1. Delete web.config first
2. Retry deleting the rest of files a number of times (loop with delay)

we still get `Access to the path '\server\app$\EntityFramework.dll' is denied.

It looks like it needs lots more time to shut down the application and release the file.

It does not happen on the other server with the same version of IIS and same system version.

Are you aware of any related bug report in dotnet core and a possible workaround?

Comment: I believe you will need to stop  IIS.

Comment: @Win :) We don't have to do any of that stuff on the other server, and it works.